# VirtualBox “Bridged Adapter” network doesn't show up in VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

ong story short, I'm trying to re-route information from an Android tablet into a CentOS VM on my Windows 7 host. I've set my Virtual Box manager to have two "Network" adapters (in Settings):

- Adapter 1 is attached to NAT and is enabled
- Adapter 2 is attached to Bridged Adapter (and the adapter type is Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop)

However, when I fire up my VM, running

```
/sbin/ifconfig
```

in bash only shows one ethernet connection (eth01) corresponding to the MAC address for Adapter 1. If I run:

`ifconfig -a` ,

an eth1 connection shows up with a MAC address matching my bridged adapter, but has no IP address.

I'm not entirely sure what to do - I've tried all promiscuous modes, and can't really seem to find anything on this specific problem online. From what I've found, most of these problems have come from the user using Wi-Fi, but I'm connected by ethernet cable.

For reference, here is my ifconfig -a:

```
eth0        Link encap: Ethernet  HWaddr 01:00:27:1D:C0:01
            inet addr: 10.0.2.15  Bcast: 10.0.2.255  Mask: 255.255.255.0
            UP BROADBAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU: 1500  Metric: 1
            RX packets: 35  errors: 0  dropped: 0  overruns: 0  frame: 0
            TX packets: 35  errors: 0  dropped: 0  overruns: 0  carrier: 0
            collisions: 0  txqueuelen:  1000
            RX bytes: 5305 (5.1 KiB) TX bytes: 3506 (3.4 KiB)

eth1        Link encap: Ethernet  HWaddr 01:00:27:39:AE:8F
            BROADBAST MULTICAST  MTU: 1500  Metric: 1
            RX packets: 0  errors: 0  dropped: 0  overruns: 0  frame: 0
            TX packets: 0  errors: 0  dropped: 0  overruns: 0  carrier: 0
            collisions: 0  txqeuelen: 1000
            RX bytes: 0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes: 0 (0.0 b)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a virtualbox-specific issue. It's the guest OS's responsibility to initialize and configure the virtual network cards, including assigning an IP address to them, just like it would be on a non-virtualized computer.

In the case of Centos, [this centos documentation page](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces-eth0.html) indicates that you can run "Network Administration Tool" (system-config-network) to configure network interfaces. The page describes how to hand-edit some configuration files if you'd rather do that. (I just googled that page; I don't know how current it is.)

In your case, it looks like you need to set CENTOS to use DHCP to configure the second interface, or you could assign it a static IP address if you'd prefer.